# How to fix search of tracks for discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

When i try to find music through discord bot my bot can't find the music. I checked in code and debug and I saw that after search in object where tracks 0 founded tracks.

And here my error in terminal -  [NoExtractors] Warning: Skipping extractors execution since zero extractors were registered.

The error is in the code part of if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song") and below

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("play a song from YouTube.")
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("search")
                .setDescription("Searches for a song and plays it")
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName("searchterms").setDescription("search keywords").setRequired(true)
                )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("playlist")
                .setDescription("Plays a playlist from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the playlist's url").setRequired(true))
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("song")
                .setDescription("Plays a single song from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the song's url").setRequired(true))
        ),
    execute: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        // Make sure the user is inside a voice channel
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) return interaction.reply("You need to be in a Voice Channel to play a song.");
        // Create a play queue for the server

        const queue = client.player.queues.create(interaction.guild)

        // Wait until you are connected to the channel
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)
        //EmbedBuilder new
        //MessageEmbed old
        let embed = new EmbedBuilder()



        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")



            // !Search for the song using the discord-player
            // !HERE ERROR
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.reply(`No results. \nurl: ${url}\nresult of search: ${result.tracks[0] === undefined ? "ТИ ЛОХ" : result.tracks[0]}`)

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}` })

        }

        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "playlist") {

            // Search for the playlist using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
            })

            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.reply(`No playlists found with ${url}`)

            // Add the tracks to the queue
            const playlist = result.playlist
            await queue.addTracks(result.tracks)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**${result.tracks.length} songs from [${playlist.title}](${playlist.url})** have been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(playlist.thumbnail)

        }
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "search") {

            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("searchterms")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.editReply("No results")

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}` })
        }

        // Play the song
        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()

        // Respond with the embed containing information about the player
        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be good, maybe try adding a catch when executes the search option, like const result = await client.player.search(url, { ... }).catch(error => console.log(error)); to get a better error tracking on the search